# How do I find value of $I$ using Node Voltage analysis method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries, electronics

[image]

How do I find value of current $I$, using [Node Voltage analysis method](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/the-node-voltage-method-for-analysis-of-electric-circuits) ?

Comment: You need [Kirchhoff's circuit law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws) .